# How to draw modules homomorphism diagram?

Tags: diagrams

This diagram is in Fuller's book "Rings and Categories of Modules". Could you help me to draw this diagram? Thank all!

[image]

Comment: This one could help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462152/14757

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to fun....excuse me...Sigur and c.p.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.5pt]
& M_1\times M_2 \arrow[dd, "h"'] \arrow[rd, "\pi_2"] &\\
0\to M_1 \arrow[ru, "i_1"] \arrow[rd, "f_1"'] & & M_2\to 0 \\
 & M \arrow[ru, "g_2"'] &         
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]